# How to format a link in a comment?

Tags: support

See [here](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/43461/what-is-the-fuel-oxygen-ratio-for-a-large-turbofan-at-cruise-conditions#43462) for my comment. It's after the answer by ymb1. I thought I used the same format as in regular posts but clearly that doesn't work. What format should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links in comments use the *other* standard format

> [Inline Link Text](http://inline-link-url.com)

More info: [Inline links in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37758/inline-links-in-comments) and [Adding links to Comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/adding-links-to-comments)

Comment: It works! Thanks.